# Ayuda con archivo .class no se visualizan

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un archivo (.jar) (que es un sistema) lo descomprimí y todos los archivos son (.class) y no puedo visualizarlos en netbeans como puedo hacer para verlos ya que necesito que estén en .java para poder trabajar en netbeans con ellos agradecería su ayuda ya que soy nuevo en este tema y no se que hacer para poder visualizarlos

Comment: ¿Quién generó el .jar en primer lugar? Pídele a esa persona que te mande el código fuente (.java)

Comment: imposible esta en el cielo

Comment: Pues lo más cercano es decompilar con decafe, JD o similares, como dicen en la respuesta. Estos programas interpretan el binario (que eso es el .class) y lo presentan sin comentarios ni otros detalles que el compilador omite. No debe asumirse que te lo va a entregar tal cual la estructura de un proyecto en un IDE. Eso es lo que hay, no vas a obtener más del JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el programa Java Decompiler con el cual puedes examinar un fichero .jar y ver sus clases asi como tambien guardar los ficheros .java

Link : http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: gracias  amigo ya lo hice pero el problema ahora es que tenia archivos .JFrame Form y ahora todos son Java Main Class y necesito ver el diseño osea las ventanas para hacerle modificación y agregar otras cosas pero cuando lo ejecuto se me muestra too perfectamente yo tengo el .exe del sistema y el .jar ay alguna forma de cargar ese .jar o el .exe en netbeans para verlo como antes